# How to lay horizontaly these views?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to implement the following layout:
[image]

I did it as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LABEL"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Text Box 1"
            android:textSize="14sp"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    >
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
        >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LABEL 2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
            />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="BLA-1"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                />

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                          android:gravity="center|bottom"
                          android:text="and"
                          android:textSize="14sp"
                />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="BLA-2"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Basically I used LinearLayouts and gravity.
It works but it seems kind of complex and I noticed that when I increase the margins left and right of the `and` text the texts `BLA-1` and `BLA-2` get cut off.
Is there a better way for this?
I think I can not use a relative layout as I would not be able to have the views take these sizes across the screen, right?

**UPDATE:**
Also with my approach any kind of padding in the TextViews cuts off the text

Comment: Check my answer below and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Have you checked my answer ? is it working or not ? let me know if you face any issue sir.

Answer (score 0):

This looks the same as on screenshot (just customize colors)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LABEL" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:hint="Text Box 1"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:textColorHint="#757575" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LABEL2" />

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:hint="BLA-1"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textColorHint="#757575" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:text="and" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:hint="BLA-2"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textColorHint="#757575" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No this is not the same. I want the textview to have more space. With your snippet they are "shrinked" together. I tested it

Comment: Hey Jim, Which TextView should have more space ? Could you please show my how are they shrinked together on screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

I think LinearLayout is a good choise even though it is complex if you want to keep the weights. 
You should change all your `TextView`s to `wrap_content` so they won't get cut off.
If you still want to avoid spaces you can wrap each `TextView` with a `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LABEL2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I use `wrap_content` then the textviews "shrink" I want them to expand all the way as in the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get it using `Linear Layout`. Have a look at below `xml` *layout* exactly what you are looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        tools:ignore="DisableBaselineAlignment">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llOne"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="LABEL"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:hint="textbox1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llTwo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="LABEL"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:hint="BLA1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="and"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llThree"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:hint="BLA2"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: This approach has the same end result as mine. It wraps the text. Also how you chose the weights is not clear to me

Comment: @Jim Could you show me the output when it wraps the text. The weights behavior is maintained on the basis of *weight sum*.